# Adding custom option while creating order programmatically is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, custom-options

I need to create an order programmatically.

I tried this code:

```
$params = array(
    'product' => $productId,
    'qty' => 1,
    'options[99]' =>time(),
    );
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
    $product->load($productId);
    $product->setSpecialPrice(250);
    $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
    $cart->save();
```

But it is not adding custom option value.

Also I tried this code:

```
$params = array(
        'product' => $productId,
        'qty' => 1,
        'options_99' =>time(),
        );
```

But no luck, can someone suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Below reolved my issue,

```
    $params = array(
            'product' => $productId,
            'qty' => 1,
            'options' => array(
                  99 => time()
                )
            );
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
    $product->load($productId);
    $product->setSpecialPrice(250);

$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
```